# What type of fish would be best suited for a trio pairing of sashimi, crudo and ceviche?

Tags: fish, crudo, sashimi, ceviche

I am preparing a trio of fish to exemplify the different ways and methods of preparing fish without cooking it in a traditional manner. The three ways I am preparing said fish will be Sashimi, Crudo, and Ceviche. I am looking for an in season, late fall pacific northwest, fish that would stand up well to all three preparation methods. It would be great if I could prepare three different fish all three ways as to give each guest nine pieces. I am considering Sea Bass and Albacore as two of the fish but have only worked with Sea Bass in a limited capacity. I also have a few guests who are "afraid" of fish and I was thinking that a Mahi Mahi or Swordfish would work well although I am not sure if either is in season.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the Albacore and Sea Bass are both great ideas. I'm not sure about the Swordfish. It would be fine in the Crudo or Ceviche, but I don't know how it would be as Sashimi.

Fish that I'd look at for this are:

- Yellowtail
- Halibut
- Tuna
- Sea Bass
- Scallops (to think outside the "fish" box a little)
- Salmon

I'm not sure if those are "in season" for you, and I can't find a good resource to determine that. I'd suggest getting a list of 5-6 fish and heading to your local fishmonger / farmers market / or Whole Foods and ask what's in season. Personally, I'd do Tuna, Yellowtail, and Scallops if you wanted to do 3x3.